# Prestashop - How to display an existing module to a new hook?

Tags: module, prestashop

Ive created a new hook and I want to add an existing module (blocktopmenu) to that hook.

The hook's name is: topMenu

Ive added this to blocktopmenu.php:

```
public function hookTopMenu($param)
  {
    global $smarty;
      $this->makeMenu();
      $smarty->assign('MENU_SEARCH', Configuration::get('MOD_BLOCKTOPMENU_SEARCH'));
      $smarty->assign('MENU', $this->_menu);
      $smarty->assign('this_path', $this->_path);
      return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blocktopmenu.tpl');
  }
```

- Ive added the module to the new hook in Modules --> Position.
- Then Ive added this to override/classes/FrontController.php:

  function displayHeader(){
              parent::displayHeader();

  ```
          self::$smarty->assign(array(
              'HOOK_HEADER' => Module::hookExec('header'),
              'HOOK_TOP' => Module::hookExec('top'),
              'HOOK_TOP_MENU' => Module::hookExec('topMenu'),
              'HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN' => Module::hookExec('leftColumn')
          ));
      }
  ```

Finally in themes/mytheme/header.tpl I have:

```
<div class="my_top_menu">{$HOOK_TOP_MENU}</div>
```

But nothing happens... the output is:

```
<div class="my_top_menu"></div>
```

Any idea how to get it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You also need to change the install function in the module to add you hook:

```
public function install(){
    if (!parent::install() OR
        !$this->registerHook('header') OR
        !$this->registerHook('topMenu') )
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Of course you need to uninstall and re-install the module after that.

Comment: I am sorry but isn't that the same as:

`return (parent::install() && $this->registerHook('header') && $this->registerHook('topMenu'));` ?

More compact and easier to read..